# What is the Patra and Mukha mentioned in Isha Upanishad?

Tags: upanishads, shukla-yajurveda

Ishavasya Upanishad of Shukla Yajurveda (actaully it's the last part of the Samhita itself) has the following verse-15:

Quoting with Adi Shankaracharya's Bhashya from [Wisdom Library](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/ishavasya-upanishad-shankara-bhashya/d/doc143816.html):

> हिरण्मयेन पात्रेण सत्यस्यापिहितं मुखम् ।
>    तत् त्वं पूषन्न् अपावृणु सत्यधर्माय दृष्टये ॥ १५ ॥
>
> hiraṇmayena pātreṇa satyasyāpihitaṃ mukham |
>   tat tvaṃ pūṣann apāvṛṇu satyadharmāya dṛṣṭaye || 15 ||
>
> 15. Truths face is covered with a golden lid;
>   remove that, O Pūṣan, that I, Truth’s devotee, may see It.
>
> **Śaṅkara’s Commentary**
>
> Hiranmayam =seeming golden, resplendent tena =by such. pātrena =lid, as it were, satyasya i.e., of the Brahman residing in the Solar disc, apihitam =covered. mukham= entrance. tat= (that); tvam =(you); he-pūṣan =O Sun, apāvṛṇu =remove. satyadharmāya i.e., to me who am through meditation on you who are Truth. Or this expression may mean “one that practises true piety” Dṛṣṭaye i.e., for reaching you whose essence is Truth.

As you can see the verse says Mukha of Satya (Truths face) is covered with a Hiranyamaya Patra (golden lid) and requesting Pushan to remove/open that Patra so-that I obtain the Satya!

This looks very mysterious and interesting spiritual preaching. I want to know more **what is the face of truth** and **what is the (Hiranyaaya) Patra** (mentioned in the verse) by which the face of truth is covered/hidden and one whose approach is Satya (that is called SatyaDharma in the verse) is preached to pray Pushan to open the cover.

Btw, This is the title song of one very useful show on Upanishads published in the form of TV Serial named [Upanishad Ganga](https://archive.org/details/upanishadganga): (I watched all the 52 episodes but this verse is not included/explained in any episode.)

[image]

And [Adi Shankaracharya's Bhashya](https://archive.org/details/isavasyopanishad00sank) doesn't elaborate much on that verse.

Comment: आदित्यमण्डलस्थ ब्रह्मका मुख ज्योतिर्मय पात्रसे ढका हुआ है । हे पूषन् मुझ सत्यधर्माको आत्माकी उपलब्धि करानेके लिये तू उसे उघाड़ दे । ~ *Hindi Translation By Gita Press Gorakhpur*

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty clear from Shankara's commentary that you have quoted. The golden disc is the visible sun. The rishi is praying to have a vision of the deeper truth beyond the physical sun i.e. the underlying Brahman. The physical golden disc of the sun (symbolically representing the entire physical universe) is brilliant, beautiful and mesmerizing. Hence it is good at hiding the meta-physical truth of Brahman.

As Brhadaranyaka Upanishad 4.3.6 says:

> अस्तमित आदित्ये याज्ञवल्क्य चन्द्रमस्यस्तमिते शान्तेऽग्नौ शान्तायां वाचि किंज्योतिरेवायं पुरुष इति आत्मैवास्य ज्योतिर्भवतीत्यात्मनैवायं ज्योतिषास्ते पल्ययते कर्म कुरुते विपल्येतीति
> Once the Sun has set, the moon has set, the fire is extinguished and Speech as stopped, what light is available to man? Atman is indeed the light. By this light he sits, goes around, does work, returns back.

So it is this truth of Atman that is behind or beyond the physical sun that the rishi is praying to see.

The same truth is expressed in symbolism in the Rig Veda mantra 6.9.7:

> विश्वे देवा अनमस्यन् भियानास्त्वामग्ने तमसि तस्थिवांसम् 
> All the deities bowed down to you in fear, O Agni, when you are sitting in the darkness.

The "Agni sitting in the darkness" is the same as the "Atman that is the light when physical sun, moon, fire, speech have all extinguished."